# backbone looses context on fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

I have a collection with a custom fetch function and a `onFetchSuccess` function.

The `onFetchSuccess` function needs to trigger some other events, so it is calling `this.trigger` and here is where it gets tricky.
It seems as if the context to `this` is lost as `trigger` is not found.

```
  fetch(options = {}) {
    console.log("fetching");
    this.trigger(this.FETCH_START);
    options.success = this.onFetchSuccess;
    options.url = this.url;
    Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
    console.log("fetched");
  }
  onFetchSuccess(model, response, options) {
    console.log("success!")
    this.trigger("change");
  }
```

it just results in `Uncaught TypeError: this.trigger is not a function`

Am I missing something? From other answers(to different questions) it seems like this is the proper way to extend the `fetch` function

Comment: try to change `onFetchSuccess` into an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), they preserve context

Comment: Or use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: @Morphyish using arrow notation seems to work. thank you!

Comment: @Morphyish please don't answer in comments, wastes peoples time reading Q&Comments thinking question is unanswered.

Comment: @TJ, you are right, I have a tendency of leaving quick suggestion in the comments when I'm not sure or when I don't have time to elaborate on an answer, as usually someone else will leave a full answer. I'll try to be more careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `onFetchSuccess` into an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Arrow functions don't have their own context, unlike regular functions. That means the `this` of an arrow function is the `this` of the context in which the function was defined, while regular functions have their own `this`.

In you case you are using a regular function definition, the `this` of `this.trigger` is actually the `this` of the function, which doesn't have a `trigger` method.

If you are using the arrow function, the `this` will be the one containing a `trigger` method as you expected.